# Firebase Firestore, How to best practice

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firebase and try to use the Firestore.

My goal is, to simply put some data in and out of the database.

```
My database looks like:
Collection: user
Document: userID
Content: 
  forename: Steve
  surename: Bobbins
```

If i'll try to acces the "forename", how would i do this on the most efficient way?
I am somewhat confused with the snapshot stuff and here's how i'm going so far:

```
DocumentSnapshot doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user").doc("21938103").snapshots().first;
print(doc["surname"]);
```

I know there is only one document with this id, but i am not sure if there are better ways to handle this.

Comment: I think you're looking for `print(doc["surname"]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user").doc("21938103").snapshots().listen(
 (event){
  String forename = event.get('forename');
  print(forename);
});
```

If you want a specific field like `forename`, you use `.get('forename')`, or the name of field you want. If you want the entire document, you use:

```
Map<String, dynamic> _map = event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
print(_map['forename']);
print(_map['surename']);
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't i not then create a listener function wich executes every time on a change? And does this not has to be closed?

Comment: I wrote snapshots because you had snapshots in it and assumed you wanted a stream. If you put it in a streambuilder widget, it takes care of everything, but if you want to run a simple function, remove snapshots().listen and keep get().then(), but be sure to use await before the get function

Comment: thank you very much, that looks like the stuff i am looking for.